# SAS Call SYMPUT - one macro variable, two values? (conditional)

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to create one macro called 'currency_rate' which calls the correct value depending on the conditions stipulated 
(either 'new_rate' or static value of 1.5):

```
%macro MONEY;
%Do i=1 %to 5;

data get_currency_&i (keep=month code new_rate currency_rate);
set Table1;   
if month = &i and  code = 'USD' then currency_rate=new_rate;
else  currency_rate=1.5;
run;

data _null_;
set get_currency_&i;
if month = &i and  code = 'USD' then currency_rate=new_rate;
else  currency_rate=1.5;
call symput ('currency_rate', ???);
run;

%End;

%mend MONEY;

%MONEY
```

I am happy with the do loop and first data step. It is the call symput I am stuck on. Is call symput the correct function to use, to assign two possible values to one macro?

A snippet example of the way I will be using 'currency_rate' in a proc sql:

```
    t1.income/&currency_rate.
```

I am a beginner level SAS user, any guidance would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let's simulate your case. Suppose we have 3 `datasets`, as shown below -

```
data get_currency_1;
    input month code $ new_rate currency_rate;
cards;
1 USD 2 2
2 CHF 2 1.5
3 GBP 1 1.5
;
data get_currency_2;
    input month code $ new_rate currency_rate;
cards;
1 USD 3 1.5
2 USD 4 4
3 JPY 0.5 1.5
;
data get_currency_3;
    input month code $ new_rate currency_rate;
cards;
1 USD 1 1.5
2 USD 3 1.5
3 USD 2.5 2.5
;
```

Now, let's run your code where we assign a value to `currency_rate`.

**Let i=1** So, the dataset `get_currency_1` will be accessed. As we run the step, each and every row will be accessed and the value of `currency_rate` will be assigned to the macro variable `currency_rate` and this iteration will continue till the end of the data step. At this time, the last value will be of currency_rate will be the final value of macro variable `currency_rate` because beyond that the step ends.

```
%let i=1;   /*Let's assign 1 to i*/
data _null_;
    set get_currency_&i;
    if month = &i and  code = 'USD' then currency_rate=new_rate;
    else  currency_rate=1.5;
    call symput ('currency_rate', currency_rate);
run;
%put Currency rate is: &currency_rate;
    Currency rate is:          1.5
```

**Let i=3:**

```
%let i=3;   /*Let's assign 3 to i*/
data _null_;
    set get_currency_&i;
    if month = &i and  code = 'USD' then currency_rate=new_rate;
    else  currency_rate=1.5;
    call symput ('currency_rate', currency_rate);
run;
%put Currency rate is: &currency_rate;
    Currency rate is:          2.5
```

You cannot have multiple values on one macro variable.

Answer (score 1):

You say you are a beginner, so the best course of action is to avoid macro programming at this point.  You would be better served learning about `where`, `merge` (or `join`) and `by` statements.

You state you will need to use a `currency_rate` in a statement such as

```
t1.income / &currency_rate.
```

The `t1.` to me suggests `t1` is an alias in a SQL join and thus the far more likely scenario is that you need to left join table `t1` that contains incomes with `table1` (call it monthly_datum) that contains the monthly currency rates.

```
select
  t1.income / coaslesce(monthly_datum.currency_rates,1.5)
, …
from
  income_data as t1
left join
  monthly_datum
on t1.month = monthly_datum.month
```

The rate of 1.5 would be used when the income is associated with a month that is not present in monthly_datum.

Answer (score 0):

A macro variable can only hold a single value. 
Since you're only ever assigning a single value, you can easily use CALL SYMPUTX().

```
 call symputx('currency_rate', currency_rate);
```

But if your data has more than one row, then the value will be the last value set in the data set.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!

Is there any other way I am able to apply these two conditions to one 'currency rate' if not a macro variable? Two different ones would not work within my queries